# Xcode4: Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIBarStyle' to different enumeration type 'UIBarButtonItemStyle'

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, styles, warnings

I have this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle: @"Secciones" 
                                                                  style: UIBarStyleDefault
                                                                 target:nil 
                                                                 action:nil];
```

and on the line that says `style: UIBarStyleDefault` I get the following warning:

> Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIBarStyle' to different enumeration type 'UIBarButtonItemStyle'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be a using UIBarStyle, but a [UIBarButtonItemStyles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonItemStyle) instead (which is, as the name suggests, meant to be used for [UIBarButtonItems](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithTitle: @"Secciones" 
    style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
    target:nil 
    action:nil
];
```

Comment: @user911524: No problem. Even though it may seem kind of selfish, you should accept answers that solved your problem :)